# Angular "select" binding to a true/false value not working

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-value

I'm trying to bind my `select` element to a true/false value.  The binding seems to happen as the `-- select --` option isn't shown, meaning Angular knows there's a value, but the display is just blank by default.  If I click on it then I see my Yes and No choices, but it's not being initially set.

```
        <select class="form-control" id="primary" name="primary" required
                [(ngModel)]="primaryValue">
            <option *ngIf="primaryValue === null" [ngValue]="null">-- Select --</option>
            <option [ngValue]="true">Yes</option>
            <option [ngValue]="false">No</option>
        </select>
```

The `primaryValue` is defined like this in the typescript file:

```js
@Input() primaryValue: boolean;
```

If I do this with just an input it works fine, but if I use primaryValue as both input and output, then it doesn't work.  You can see an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wd6s6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It appears to work well in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ix2byy). I simulated a delayed assignment but it also works if `primaryValue` is set to `true` when declared. Is the `select` element inside of a `form` and, if so, does it have a unique name? Maybe `primaryValue` has the string value `"true"`, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd67d6).

Comment: I think you have to implement 'OnChanges' lifecycle, since the value is passed from an input decorator, therefore value from input decorator is received after the rendering has completed. **The binding seems to happen as the -- select -- option isn't shown** ... yes, that is happening because the @Input value is undefined (when rendering) so not option is shown at all

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have it working elsewhere as well, which is why I'm so confused.  The value is defined as a boolean, and the webservice is definitely returning just `true` and not the string true.

Comment: @Gargoyle but undefined === null is false so if primaryValue is undefined `<option *ngIf="primaryValue === null" [ngValue]="null">-- Select --</option>`wont show

Comment: @GabrielLopez Yes, sorry I read your initial comment wrong.  Is the `OnChanges` different from using the getter/setter pattern?  Updated the question to show I'm explicitly using that now.

Comment: Just made this really quick to show it... [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-u1ow9s) , relevant code is in files  "app.component.html","ModalContent/modalContent.component.ts" and "ModalContent/modalContent.component.html"

Comment: OK, it's something to do with having two-way binding.  Finally got a small [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wd6s6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) that shows it.

Comment: Try `[(primaryValue)]` instead of `([primaryValue])`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jahqgj).

Comment: Dang it.  My real source has it the right way.  Still searching for a minimal breakage example.

Comment: hey @Gargoyle...   I'm Looking at your StackBlitz, what you are trying to achieve is to set value on the second select depending on what was selected on the first one?

Comment: @GabrielLopez Yes, that's part of it.  It's a group of 3 questions, and if the first is yes, then the other two become enabled and required.  I have multiple of these on the parent component.

Comment: @Gargoyle [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dependentselect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally tracked this down.  In the component that showed the questions I had this as part of the `@Component` definition:

```js
viewProviders: [  // This makes the whole child participate in the parent's form validation
    {
        provide: ControlContainer,
        useExisting: NgForm
    }
]
```

which I had seen on the web say that it makes the child controller's components be part of the parent component's form validation.  As soon as I removed that part, everything started working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the `boolean` value to set the initial value.

```
<app-lab-hazard-classification-question-group 
    (change)="onHazardValueChanged($event)"
    primaryQuestion="Primary Question One"
    [primaryValue]="true"                         <!-- Set the boolean value -->
    secondaryQuestion="Secondary Question One" 
    [secondaryValue]="false">                     <!-- Set the boolean value -->
</app-lab-hazard-classification-question-group>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5mdctu

Answer (score 0):

Two-Way binding is also called as "Banana in a box" binding i.e. [()].

Inside your AppComponent.html, reverse the order of parenthesis for correct binding

```
<app-question-group [(primaryValue)]="valueOne"></app-question-group>
```